# Put names of .txt files into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

This is my code, pinched from this site:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("C:\\"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file = file.strip(".txt")
        print(file)
```

It works great, but I want to be able to manipulate my results and store them into a list, and I'm not sure how to do that. It's probably super simple and missing me completely, I'm sort of a noob. Thanks :)

EDIT:

I removed the readlines part, that wasn't meant to be there.
What I am trying to do is get the names of every .txt file in the folder, in this case the folder is C:\

Comment: "Manipulate my results" you mean the `readlines()` or the `file`?

Comment: `os.listdir("C:\\")` already returns a list of all the files in that directory

Comment: And I don't think this code should work... `file.readlines()` should error with `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'`

Comment: Why don't you define an empty list and append the file names to it ?

Comment: @Ian Forget the readlines part, it wasn't meant to be there! I mean I want to manipulate a list populated with the file names.

Comment: @kanayamalakar I tried, but it would only add one of the names out of 2 for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to have something like this:

```
import os
allfiles = os.listdir('C:\\')
onlytxt = [x for x in allfiles if x.endswith('.txt')]
print onlytxt
```

if you don't want to have .txt in the list do this:

```
onlytxt = [x[:-4] for x in allfiles if x.endswith('.txt')]
```

Comment: Brilliant. Does exactly what I need, no fuss. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple alternatives to incBrain's (perfectly fine) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36579910/364696).

First, to simplify your own code instead of reinventing the wheel, use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
import glob

onlytxt = [file[:-4] for file in glob.glob('C:\\*.txt')]
```

Or to get higher performance on Python 3.5+ (or any version of Python using the `scandir` module from PyPI):

```
import os  # Pre-3.5, you'd import and use the scandir module from PyPI

# Use file.path[:-4] to store the full path (sans .txt extension)
# where file.name[:-4] only gets the file name without the path or extension
onlytxt = [file.name[:-4] for file in os.scandir('C:\\') if file.name.endswith('.txt')]
```

Or for true ridiculousness, push more work to the C layer and avoid redundancy by splitting off the extension once, instead of one check for it, then another operation to strip it:

```
import os
from operator import attrgetter

components = map(os.path.splitext, map(attrgetter('name'), os.scandir('C:\\')))
onlytxt = [root for root, ext in components if ext == 'txt']
```

`os.scandir` doesn't do much for you in this case (you're not reading any attributes it might have checked for you), but in a largish directory, it means you aren't storing all entries at once (`os.listdir` and most other APIs read the complete contents of the directory into a `list` first before you have a chance to filter it), so peak memory usage is reduced when few files are matched.